# Reference to group function not supported

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am receiving the following error from the below query, as I am trying to order the results by a value being retrieved in the query itself. Please can you tell me how I can get around this error, I am guessing by creating a sub-query within the query, of which I don't know how to!

```
SELECT q.*, COUNT(DISTINCT a.qid) AS `a_count`
FROM `questions` AS q
INNER JOIN `answers` AS a
ON a.qid = q.id
ORDER BY MAX(a_count)
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: What is the query supposed to do?

Comment: order by a_count desc limit 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `ORDER BY MAX(a_count)`, as that doesn't make sense. (You can't really sort by a single value)

You probably wanted to do `ORDER BY a_count`.

Comment: Hi Mitch, thanks for the reply, and it's working perfectly. One thing that is occurring is that not all of the rows are being selected, just one. Please could you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `GROUP BY MAX(a_count)` then? What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: I'm trying to order the questions in the db by their popularity, number of answers.

Comment: Oh, in that case: `SELECT q.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM answers WHERE question_id=q.id) AS a_count FROM questions ORDER BY a_count DESC LIMIT 0,10`